# como colocar 2 o mas tablas en columnas

Tags: html, css

Tengo dos tablas una la llamare X la otra Y

```
+-------+
|Tabla x|
+-------+
```

y la otra es

```
+-------+
|Tabla Y|
+-------+
```

Cuando creo el codigo html seria el siguiente:

```css
td {
  border: 1px dashed goldenrod;
}

table {
  border: 2px dashed cyan;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Tabla X</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Tabla Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

MI pregunta es que cuando creo las tablas me sale una debajo de otra ejemplo:

```
+-------+
|Tabla x|
+-------+
+-------+
|Tabla Y|
+-------+
```

Pero quiero que el hmtl me las muestre asi:

```
+-------+ +-------+
|Tabla x| |Tabla Y|
+-------+ +-------+
```

¿Cual seria el codigo CSS para realizar dicha accion?

Comment: ¿Y deben ser tablas independientes? lo digo por que a como muestras el resultado parece que alcanza con que sea una sola tabla

Comment: Uso de Grids boostrap 4 - [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Ahora si así como esta quieres mover una *tabla* a lado de la otra entonces alcanza de *rápido* con hacer **`table{ display: inline; }`**

Comment: Faltaría especificar claramente la salida que esperas. Hay varias formas de lograr lo que intentas, pero sin saber que resultado buscas, no se puede saber cual es la que más te conviene. Si hasta puedes meter una tabla dentro de otra tabla !!! XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con *style="float: left;"* puedes hacer "flotar" la tabla, lo cual te permite colocar una al lado de la otra.

En el ejemplo, le agregué la opción de bordes y el ancho en 50% para cada una, a fin de que se vea mejor el efecto.

```html
<table border="1" style="float: left;" width="50%">
<tr><td>Tabla X</td></tr>
</table>

<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr><td>Tabla Y</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 Sería genial que agregaras que esa es la forma en que [tag:bootstrap] funcionaba antes de que existiera flexbox.

Comment: Por supuesto, pero esa no era su pregunta.

Comment: Exacto, extenderse más de lo solicitado puede llevar a confusiones al OP.

Comment: amigo ultima pregunta se puede separar un poco? al menos 5px?

Comment: Elimina el `border="1"` e incluye dentro del style lo siguiente: `style="float: left; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;"`

Answer (score 1):

Te he compilado varias opciones
Realmente, las que tienen más libertad y facilidad, para mí 
Son las `Tabla dentro de Tabla` Y el `Grid System` de Boostrap.
Pero como dije, realmente depende de que resultado quieres obtener tu.
**Vee a Página Completa los resultados para que veas las distintas tablas**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="col-1" style="width: 100%">
                <table border="1" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 100px; width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Tabla 1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            GRIDS
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <table border="1" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 100px; width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Tabla 2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            GRIDS
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="1" style="background-color: darkkhaki; height: 100px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Tabla 3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            TABLA TABLA
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table border="1" style="background-color: yellow; height: 100px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Tabla 4
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            TABLA TABLA
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" style="float:left; background-color:lightskyblue; height:100px; width: 5%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Tabla 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                FLOAT
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" style="background-color:lightseagreen; height:100px; width: 5%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Tabla 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                NO FLOAT
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" style="background-color:palevioletred; height:100px; display: inline-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Tabla 7
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                INLINE TABLE
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" style="background-color:mediumpurple; height:100px; display:inline-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Tabla 8
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                INLINE TABLE
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Es difícil diferenciar donde empieza y termina el otro ejemplo y por lo mismo saber que se tiene que poner o que hace cada cosa, te recommiendo separar tu snippet de ejemplo en varios. Saludos.

Comment: Es cosa de poner comentarios, pero es un ejemplo de lo que puse en el comentario.

Answer (score -1):

#Editado
Es muy simple solo tendrias que usar contenedores en fila

```
<div style={{ flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex'}}>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>

 </div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [answer], editar y explicar hará mas simple y fácil de entender tu aporte

Comment: El idioma oficial del sitio es el español. procura responder en ese idioma.

Comment: lo lamento es la costumbre jaja

Comment: No entiendo la calificacion negativa intentas ayudar y recibes calificaciones negativas? creo que deberia ser cuando la respuesta no sea valida o perjudique de cierta forma al grupo, es como cortarle las alas a quien quiere ayudar no?